# How do I restrict access to certain web sites?

Tags: squid, elinks

I have installed elinks and squid and I need to restrict access to yahoo.com(including subdomains. for example, fr.yahoo.com). How do I permanently configure elinks(or squid) to forbid access to yahoo.com?

Answer (score 3):

**Using Squid**

First create a file name `acl.txt` and put it under `/home/` or `/etc/` and put 
`.yahoo.com` inside it (`.`will include sub domains )

After that Put this configuration line under `squid.conf`

I assume you put acl.txt under /etc/squid/

```
acl denyThis dstdomain "/etc/squid/acl.txt" 
http_access deny denyThis 
http_access allow all 
acl our_networks src 192.168.1.0/24
http_access allow our_networks
```

By this lines we allow all requests from any ip that belong to network 192.168.1.0 with mask 255.255.255.0 except requests that have a destination domain contains is file /etc/squid/acl.txt.

[Check Squid Configuration Basics](http://www.deckle.co.za/squid-users-guide/Squid_Configuration_Basics) For more knowledge :)

Comment: I tried to access yahoo.com from elinks and it worked. Do I have to  somehow connect elinks with squid?

Comment: @johnny I don't think you can block elinks and Tor using squid.